# Ag-grid - None of the events(onRowClick, onRowSelected etc) fires after opening context menu 2nd time onwards

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using custome context menu in ag-grid. I observed that once I open context menu after right click on row after this no event fires (rowSelected, rowClicked) even context menu popup closed after left clock.

```
[getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems"
(rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"
(rowClicked)="onRowClick($event)"
```

Scenario to reproduce -

Handle Event `(rowClicked)="onRowClick($event)"` or `(rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"`.

Left click on any row/cell anytime, These events are firing.

Now right click on any cell to open context menu. Now close the context menu without any selection by left click.. Now try left click on any row/cell above events are not firing.

Note:- I also tried - `(cellContextMenu)="cellContextMenu($event)"`.. This is only firing first time when we open context menu through right click. Now close by left click, Again do right click to open context menu.. Its opening but cellContextMenu event is not firing.

ag-grid-angular, Version - 20.1.0

Manish

Comment: please show your code - a StackBlitz would be most helpful.

Comment: Check this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eqlaa1PmHd7BPuED), I have captured rowClicked event. Do left click multiple times, alert will open accordingly. Now, do right click means context menu open. After this try left click again.. rowClicked is NOT firing. Once context menu opened, rowClicked event will not fire afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use

```
(rowClicked)="yourFuntion($event)"
```

instead of

```
(onRowClicked)="yourFuntion($event)"
```